# Cordova run function in background

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugins

Before opening this question, I researched here and what I had was not what I needed.

I'm using the plugins:

- [cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-network-information](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information)
- [cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-background-mode](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode)

Reading the doc I arrived at this montage:

```
document.addEventListener("online", onOnline, false);
function onOnline() {
    let networkState = navigator.connection.type

    if (networkState == "wifi") {
       
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
            cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.enable();
            cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.isScreenOff(function() {
                
                setInterval(function(){ 
                    alert('Alert executed in the background')
                

                    cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.setDefaults({
                        title: 'Title',
                        text: 'Text',
                        icon: 'www/img/res/mipmap-xxxhdpi/ico.png',
                        color: 'F14F4D',
                        resume: true,
                        hidden: false,
                        bigText: true
                    })

                }, 5000);

            });
        }, false);

        
    }
}
```

But the result is nothing, there is no error, nor does the alert run when the app is closed.

I need the alert to run with the app closed and the icon appears at the top of the phone bar, symbolizing that something is running.

Thanks.

Comment: "nor does the alert run when the app is closed." - I think this background plugin is for app to be in background not closed.

Comment: @MosheYamini I also left it in the background, and it didn't run.

Answer (score 0):

Try to switch the order you registering to the events.

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
            cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.enable();
            cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.isScreenOff(function() {

            });
            document.addEventListener("online", onOnline, false);

        }, false);

function onOnline() {
    let networkState = navigator.connection.type
        if (networkState == "wifi") {
            setInterval(function(){ 
                    alert('Alert executed in the background')
                

                    cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.setDefaults({
                        title: 'Title',
                        text: 'Text',
                        icon: 'www/img/res/mipmap-xxxhdpi/ico.png',
                        color: 'F14F4D',
                        resume: true,
                        hidden: false,
                        bigText: true
                    })

                }, 5000);
         }
}
```